# What is the reason for 'Query condition missed key schema element' in AWS DynamoDb?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Here is my code to fetch all elements that has a text as 'Make a dinner'.

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'todos',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'todoName = :t',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':t': 'Make a dinner' }
  };

db.scan(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
});
```

I get this error:

> Query condition missed key schema element: todo_id

What is the reason for this error? How to avoid it? I have only primary key in my table, no sort key.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It sounds like `todo_id` is your primary key. You are trying to query on `todoName`. You can't query on non-key fields.

You either need to run a `scan` instead of a `query`, or change your query to use `todo_id` instead of `todoName`, or change your table primary key to be `todoName`, or add a global secondary index on `todoName`.

Comment: But `scan` fetches all elements and only after does filtering. It is not efficient, I suppose. You mean that, in order to use `query`, I definitely need to use `todo_id`?

Comment: Query only works against index fields. You can't run a query against a non index field. If you could run query against any field then there would be no reason for `scan` to exist. If you want to run a query instead of an inefficient scan, you have to use a field you have defined in either the primary key, or a secondary index.

Comment: @MarkB this is entirely true, you cannot use solely secondaryIndex to `query` a table, aws doesn't let you, you must supply a filtering value for partition key, which is indexed by default, I believe.

Comment: @YuriyKravets the entire reason DynamoDB Global Secondary Indexes exist, is to allow you to `query` against those secondary indexes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html